# how do i prevent a rogue app from hitting my database services and imitating my app?

Tags: android, ios, security

We have one team working on our back-end database and one working on the app. The mobile developers have access to the full source code of the mobile app. if someone leaves with the full source code of our app and just re-launches the app on the app store... what prevents them from using our database?

is there anyway i can prevent this? i like how the open source code allows rapid deployment of developers and open collaboration and testing. but it is a risk that i would like to eliminate and sleep better on. We have NDA's, etc in place..but still.

Comment: u can use oAuth2 and other techniques

Comment: The `oAuth2` is working for log in and stuff like that. You will probably found solution here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42586/ensure-web-service-only-accessed-by-authorized-applications, but the short answer is that you can't really do that.